# How to increase script execution time at my server

Tags: plugins, theme-development

I am trying to run string locator plugin to find some strings in my theme directory. but whenever i try to run this plugin, following error ocures
"Warning
The maximum time your server allows a script to run is too low for the plugin to run as intended, at startup 2 seconds have passed"

I have tried to increase max exeecution time for script in php.ini by going to 
Xampp control panel click config> php.ini .... but nothing changed.
is there any other way to make this plugin work?
thanks!

Comment: After updating the php.ini you need to restart the services (Apache and MySql). 

Another option is to run: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` to see where and which php version is running. It could be that you are changing the wrong `php.ini`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author of the plugin says it this problem was fixed in [release 2.0.3](https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/string-locator.2.0.3.zip) . You may also check the original thread in [WordPress support](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/loved-it-until-upgrading-to-hhvm/) .

Answer (score 0):

Add this code on your .htaccess file

```
php_value max_execution_time 300
```